# How Do I access header information in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

First off I am new to PowerShell and have written code in many different languages. Most of my experience was from java so typically I format my code from that background so I apologize it if it looks crazy.

I am trying to make a script that I can run against a CSV that will load each of the objects into an array. I want to then check each object to make sure it has an e-mail address, Firstname, and Lastname attached to it. We are currently deleting invalid entries by hand.

I have the following code below that I am working with. I am attempting to import the CSV. I want to read each element in the array and remove the entries that are not meeting my criteria, I then want to export that to a CSV.  I am confused on what the objects look like in the array, how to check if the information in each object is null. Any assistance on logic would be nice. The CSV has the headers listed below, but I only care about the onces listed above. Thanks,
'
    $csv = Read-Host "enter file path to CSV"

```
$CsvArray = Import-Csv $csv -Header Lastname,Firstname,Department,Phonenumber,Email

  foreach ($i in $CsvArray)
   {
     Write-Host $CsvArray($i)

  if(Lastname -eq $NULL) -or (firstname -eq $NULL) -or (Email -eq $NULL)
     {
       Delete $i from array 
      }
  else
     {
     $i
     }
 } 

 $csvArray | Export-Csv c:\emaillist.txt -force


 Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."

$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$CsvArray = Import-Csv $csv -Header Lastname,Firstname,Department,Phonenumber,Email |
Where-Object { $_.Lastname -ne $null -and $_.Firstname -ne $null -and $Email -ne $null } |
Export-Csv C:\emaillist.txt -force
```

Comment: You could shorten that middle bit to `?{$_.Lastname -and $_.Firstname -and $_.Email}` ...and it may just be me but I always use `-NoTypeInfo` when I `Export-CSV`

Comment: I changed my code after I posted this to have the $_.Lastname etc and it appears to run, but I was not getting any returns, unless i put code in the first if statement. I tried your solution which is much more streamlined than what I was trying to do, but it also gave me a blank file. So it seems like the condition is not working properly. I know I have many entries that either do not have email or do not have both a first and last name

Comment: I would change the condition to test this - start off with just $_.Lastname -ne $null in the Where-Object. Assuming you get output, then it's just a matter of fine-tuning your condition.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - you're right, the "-ne $null" is unnecessary. I prefer to be explicit about what I'm testing, so tend to include it, but it is not needed. And yes, I usually use -NoTypeInfo as well. I left it off since the original question did not include it.

Comment: Well I thought it was working but it is in fact not, I tried the following code:                                                        Import-Csv $csv -Header Lastname,Firstname,department, Phonenumber,Email |
Where-Object {$_.Lastname -ne $null -and $_.Firstname -ne $null} | Out-Host                                                              and it outputs every entry to the out, its not filtering entries with null values. any idea?

Comment: It's possible that they don't have null values, but empty strings. Try ![String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Lastname) instead of $_.Lastname -ne $null.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking that they might be empty and not null. I implemented the code you suggested and I am now getting the proper output. thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Ok, `![String]::IsNullOrEmpty()` is awesome, why have I never seen this before? Thank you KevinD, I've run into empty strings before and always had to fake my way past it with ugly and clumsy scripts before.

Comment: Depending on what version of PowerShell / .NET you're running, you can also use ![String]::IsNullorWhiteSpace($variable). And yes, very useful indeed. Glad it helped you!